# 400 Error with Javascript Rdio API

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, rdio

Any thoughts on why I'm getting a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" in the Javascript on my client? (client-id obscured, I have one for an Oauth2.0 app via registration Rdio site)

index.html:

```
 <script src="https://www.rdio.com/api/api.js?client_id=12345678"></script>
```

response:

```
https://www.rdio.com/oauth2/authorize/auto?response_type=token&client_id=12345678&showSignup=true&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fhelper.html%3Fclient_id%3D12345678

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response text from the `https://www.rdio.com/oauth2/authorize/auto` request should reveal the error. For example, making a request from the shell:

```
$ curl "https://www.rdio.com/oauth2/authorize/auto?response_type=token&client_id=12345678&showSignup=true&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fhelper.html%3Fclient_id%3D1234567"
```

For a valid client ID, a possible response might be:

> Invalid redirect_uri

If this is the error you're receiving, which seems likely, to resolve it, you need to add your `redirect_uri`'s domain to the Redirect URIs in [your Rdio application's settings](http://www.rdio.com/developers/your-apps/).

Comment: That was indeed helpful. The redirect uri needed to be added in the settings